# Issue binding to sub view

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

This is the simplest of issues, probably, but I am stumped and cannot find where anyone else has had this problem before; need help with displaying a header within shell.html.

At this point, I'm just trying to get this to work, so everything is as simple as possible.

My visual element is made up of index.cshtml, which has a div named 'applicationHost'. I am able to successfully load shell.html into that div via:

```
`app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');`
```

which is a line of code residing in main.js and is called from index.cshtml using:

```
`<script data-main="App/main" src="/scripts/require.js"></script>`
```

Inside shell.html, I have a div, which should display header.html. The div in shell.html is defined as:

```
`<div id="shellHeader" data-bind="compose:{ model: 'viewmodels/header' }">`
```

header.html is simply:
    `<div>

        <span id="someSpan" data-bind="text: title"></span>

    </div>`

In turn, header.js is defined as:
    `var header = (function () {
    var title = 'what I want to display in the someSpan div';
    var header = {
        title: title
    };
    return header;
    })();`

When I run the app, I get no error, and #applicationHost indeed loads shell.html, as seen from the Elements tab in the Chrome developer tools:
    `<div id="applicationHost">
        <div class="durandal-wrapper" 
        data-view="views/shell" 
        data-active-view="true">
        </div>
        <div id="shellHeader"
            data-bind="compose:{ model: 'viewmodels/header' }">
    </div>

    </div>`

Nothing is displayed in #shellHeader. Same thing is true if I use comment syntax:
    `<!-- ko compose: { viewmodel: 'header' } -->
    <!-- /ko -->`

(or if I change the above comment to read:
    `<!-- ko compose: { model: 'viewmodels/header' } -->
    <!-- /ko -->`
    , still no display, but also no error message in console)

However, if I change viewmodel to view, I do get the header.html to load, but with the error stating that 'title' is not defined, which I interpret to mean that the header.js file is not included in the rendered element - I believe a view without the backing module was created and inserted into the #shellHeader element.

If I add the following line to header.js:
    `ko.applyBindings(header)`;

to the end of the file, I get an error message stating (something to the effect that) you cannot apply multiple bindings...

I have seen where the router object is used to render models, but I don't think that applies here. I'm just trying to load an html object inside an html object inside a cshtml object, and bind to the properties exposed via the header.js module (in this case).

Seems like this should be the simplest thing in the world to do, but I cannot figure it out. What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answered one question, but raised another:

For anyone else experiencing a similar problem, I believe the answer to be the context to which the header.html was actually being bound (and my issue, in retrospect, would be to bind to the header.js context, rather than to the shell.html's context).

I solved the problem by adding the 'title' property to the shell.js returned object, and used this comment for the binding in shell.html:

```
<!-- ko compose: {view: header } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

So, the moral to the story appears to be that the header.html view is bound to the context of its parent, shell.html, and THAT context is what properties in header.html have to be bound to.

The issue now is, how do you bind to the header.js context object rather than the shell's context?

Comment: Is header.js defined as an AMD module?

Comment: As RainerAtSpirit is asking: your code for header.js  does not how a define([], function () { }) wrapper. This could very well be the cause of the problem. It is not usual that the header view is bound to its parent's context. The compose binding composes the view and its own viewmodel together.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! If I change my header.js to read:

Comment: @RainerAtSprint Thank you very much for responding! If I change my header.js to read: define([], function () {
    var title = 'what I want to display in #someSpan';
    return {
        title: title
    };
})(); and then remove the 'title' property from shell.js, once again I get the message 'title is not defined', and the #someSpan element is not displayed. Interestingly, I was able to add the line ko.applyBindings('header') line of code in header.js with no error, although that may be because it's executing as an immediate function and may be returning before hitting that code??)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine your header view model and view together, I believe that you would want to just do:

`ko compose: 'header'`

or if the paths are slightly different than you could specify it like:

`ko compose: { model: 'foo', view: 'bar/foo' }`

Comment: Thank you, Sir! That did the trick. I don't have the juice to vote this up, but I was able to accomplish my goal with your answer. I'll see if I can mark this as the answer. Thanks again!